# Is there a convenient way to find questions which I have previously answered?

Tags: support

I started my participation yesterday, and I was very gratefully and pleasantly surprised to receive a perfect answer.

I also looked through 10 pages of unanswered questions, and I answered a few. Now I wiould like to take a look at these questions I answered to see if my answers were useful.  I have not been able to find any search method for doing this efficiently.

Comment: BTW, if you are pleased by the answer to your question then you can click on the tick (✔️) button to accept those answers. It tells the answerer that you have appreciated their response.

Comment: Also we have voting system to maintain the quality of our content. You may soon be eligible to vote yourself (after you gain 15 reputations).

Comment: If you haven't already visited our tour page, then you should definitely go there and check out about our policies, etc. Here's the link: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Did you look at the help center page about [searching](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching)?

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 9):

Go to your user profile, click "activity" towards the top of the page. you should find anything you need.

You can find your user profile by clicking on your user name under any post you have made (such as this question); there is also a link with your profile image in the top bar.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the listings in your profile page, the modifiers `user:me` and `is:answer` can be used in any search to limit the search to your posts and to answers, respectively. For more information, see [How do I search?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching) on the Help Center.